# How to post to LinkedIn company page instead of personal page

Tags: php, linkedin-api

It's been a week and I cannot post to the company page.
The below code works but it's sending to my personal profile instead of the company page.
Anyone can advise, please?

```
<?php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
  
$link = 'www.google.com';
$access_token = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';
$linkedin_id = 'EWg7hNHQ9F';

$body = new \stdClass();
$body->content = new \stdClass();
$body->content->contentEntities[0] = new \stdClass();
$body->text = new \stdClass();
$body->content->contentEntities[0]->thumbnails[0] = new \stdClass();
$body->content->contentEntities[0]->entityLocation = $link;
$body->content->contentEntities[0]->thumbnails[0]->resolvedUrl = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
$body->content->title = 'Testing Only';
$body->owner = 'urn:li:person:'.urlencode($linkedin_id);
$body->text->text = 'Testing summary';
$body_json = json_encode($body, true);
  
try {
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.linkedin.com']);
    $response = $client->request('POST', '/v2/shares', [
    // $response = $client->request('POST', '/v2/ugcPosts', [
        'headers' => [
            'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
            "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $access_token,
            "Content-Type"  => "application/json",
            // "x-li-format"   => "json"
        ],
        'body' => $body_json,
    ]);
  
    if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 201) {
        echo 'Error: '. $response->getLastBody()->errors[0]->message;
    }
  
    echo 'Post is shared on LinkedIn successfully.';
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(). ' for link '. $link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just skimmed the API docs, Maybe your URN is wrong?

`urn:li:organization    Organization Share  Share was created by a member for an organizational entity. The organization or brand is displayed as the publisher.`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?tabs=http

Other Reference: [Post an article to company LinkedIN page via REST api (v2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831436/post-an-article-to-company-linkedin-page-via-rest-api-v2)

Comment: Thank you @ghgg, I tried to put
`$body->owner = 'urn:li:organization:123456;`
But then I got the following error
Client error: `POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"message":"com.linkedin.content.common.exception.BadRequestResponseException: Company owned UGCs cannot have CONNECTION (truncated...)

Comment: Could you post the full error message?

Comment: Client error: `POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processin (truncated...) for link google.com

Comment: To me, it seems those are two different errors? The 403 Forbidden stands out, you might not have the correct permissions. try looking here for the 403 error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/error-handling

Comment: Another hint, Unpermitted fields in REQUEST_BODY it says in your error, I would check your  body_json and see if something is messing you up in that too.

Comment: I tried a lot and nothing seems to work. I checked the permissions and body and everything. I'll try a different approach. Do you know any sample codes resources for linkedIn?

Comment: I don't, I've never used the API, I would suggest going through the docs. I also suggest changing the body up and seeing if that changes anything. It's strange that you can post to your personal, but not the company page. There has to be a reason buried in the docs somewhere. Look at other examples of posting to company pages with the Linkedin API regardless of whether it's in PHP or not. I looked up "linkedin api example code post to company page" found this among others: https://www.jcchouinard.com/how-to-post-on-linkedin-api-with-python/
Sorry I don't have a definite answer for you

Comment: if/when you figure it out please update this question with what worked :)

Comment: I will keep trying and post an update if I find a solution. Thank you so much for all the effort :)